# Android SDK Tool, Revision 12 not erase user information anymore?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I just updated my android sdk tool to revision 12 today. I usually check the box "wipe user data" before launching an AVD. But now it seems like rev 12 is keeping all my settings (not resetting the simulator to the original state). Anyone else runs into this problem? Is the only solution just to create a new AVD every time?

Edit: The reason I am wiping user data every time is due to my app is coded to copy over a default database on the first use. i am using different initial db to test different things.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the exact answer you're looking for but, if it helps, Android Documentation states that you can start your AVD (using command line) with some additional Options to wipe the user data i.e.: c:\android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator -avd hero -wipe-data

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Best

-serkan

Answer (score 1):

If you have your avd's in /root/.android/myAPI8.avd
owned by root
and you now try to run "emulator -wipe-data myAPI8.avd" with user jenkins
the jenkins user is not permitted to delete files,
and -wipe-data fails silently,
BUT the emulator still starts with the old user data in place.

If you remove the /root/.android/myAPI8.avd folder,
the jenkins user will now fail with "SDL init failure" instead.

I don't have a workaround.

You may have a user permission issue,
not an SDK issue.

Comment: well i've checked my avd, which is located under $HOME/.android/avd/, the permission is set to owner with write access, group and other don't. So i am a bit puzzled here.

It's not the biggest deal in the world. I can always delete the avd and start a new one. I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an acknowledged bug in R12 of the developer tools.  See [issue 18444](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18444)

Answer (score 0):

Click the Tools menu
Tools--> Android --> AVD Manager
Select your AVD and click the dropdown and select wipe data and confirm it by clicking YES.